# How do I disconnect a user from a discord channel with discord js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

The main issue seems to be that things are undefined. For example, a very simple version of something I have tried:

```
else if (message.content.startsWith("!dc")) {
    message.author.voice.setChannel(null);
}
```

Resulting in the terminal returning:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setChannel')

I'm not quite sure how to "define" these as some solutions I've found online seem to do what I am trying to do in a similar way. Am I just missing something obvious?

I also have these Intents declared at the top.

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
intents: [
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS
    ]
});
```

Comment: it'd be msg.member

Comment: Wow. The hours I could have saved if I ran into you sooner. LOL
Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is a method used for disconnecting users from voice chat. `message.member.voice.disconnect()`

Comment: @spect423 which uses the `.setChannel(null)`: see the [source](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/structures/VoiceState.js#L191)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Bee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14687396/bee) said [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71027698/how-do-i-disconnect-a-user-from-a-discord-channel-with-discord-js/71027868#comment125560455_71027698) to my question:

> it'd be `msg.member`

Comment: It would be better to provide the info here, as comments aren't permanent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can disconnect yourself while you are admin.
So try this

```js
return <member>.voice.setChannel(null)
    .then(() => message.channel.send(`Done`))
    .catch((err) => message.channel.send(`\\❌ | ${err}!`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
message.member.voice.disconnect()
    .catch(console.error);
```